# Android: Bitmap image is distorted when rotates

Tags: android, bitmap, image-rotation

i have a rotating bitmap in my application, but it gets really distorted and pixelated, anything i can do?

i am referring to the clock hand.

[image]

Comment: Is your algorithm resizing the bitmap as it rotates it?  Look here:  http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/rotate-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to try to rotate an image in a paint program, I believe you would get similar results. It's due to the fact it has to draw it at a weird angle, which generally requires more pixels to "look right". If you rotate it from 12 to 3, 6, or 9 I'm betting it wouldn't be as pixelated.

Try using a bitmap that is of higher pixel density - rotate, then scale it down to size. That might help.

Comment: Yes that should work, but what do u mean scale down? i try to do matrix.scale(0.75,0.75) to shrink it but it only accepts float? so what do i do?